# Any opensource SDK availiable like that of whatsapp

Tags: sdk, whatsapp

is any opensource messenger availiable ( SDK )  which has similar interface and functinality like that of whatsapp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to Telegram: https://telegram.org/source

It has a public API and the service is quite good.